# Can't use php in tpl files - cs-cart

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I'm trying to create a tpl called `billet.tpl` for payment methods, and I need to use PHP on it to get some information about the order and to generate the URL to the billet, but every time I put `{php} {/php}` on it, I get an error when I try to change to this new payment method as customer:

> 500 Internal Server Error

This is the code:

```
{php} 
global $base_domain;

$orderInfo = $this->get_template_vars('order_info');
  .
  .
  .
{/php}

<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio_boleto" checked/>Billet Payment
```

This is the console error:

> http://dev.aparelhosmedicos.com/checkout.html?active_tab=tab4&payment_id=12&full_render=true&result_ids=checkout*%2Cstep_four&is_ajax=1
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Ps: I already changed the `allow_php_templates` to true in file `Smarty.class.php`. What I'm doing wrong? Is there another variable that I should set to true or something? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried? Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to best show us a minimal but complete example of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I just made some adjustments.

Comment: i think you don't have the `$this` context. have a look in your error logs on the server

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code in smarty instead of using {php} tags which were disabled due to security reasons.

```
{$order_info = $smarty.request.order_id|fn_get_order_info}
{$order_info|fn_print_r}
```

Hope this will help.